# Change File Access Permission of Text File While Open VB

Tags: vb.net, file, ms-access, file-permissions

I'm looking to change the access permission of the text file from Input to Append depending on what operation needs to be done in the code. It is set at Input when opened as the first operation is to read the data, but how to I change it to Append without closing the file?

My code:

```
FileOpen(1, username & DateTime.Now.ToString(" hh-mm dd-MM-yyyy") & ".txt", OpenMode.Input)
    'y = senArray.Count

    For Each x In senArray
            If LineInput(1) = senArray(x) Then
                lineTemp = LineInput(1)
                PrintLine(1, lineTemp & " " & j)
                If LineInput(1) = "" Then
                    PrintLine(1, senArray(x) & " " & j)
                End If
            Else
            End If
            j += 1
    Next
    FileClose(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A file's properties cannot be modified whilst it is open, I suggest using something such as File.AppendAllText or something more suited for what you need to do, which basically implements FileOpen and all that stuff but handles it better and its probably faster.